# When should I use string_view in an interface?

Tags: c++, api-design, strings

I'm using an internal library that was designed to mimic a [proposed C++ library](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4478.html), and sometime in the past few years I see its interface changed from using `std::string` to `string_view`.

So I dutifully change my code, to conform to the new interface. Unfortunately, what I have to pass in is a std::string parameter, and something that is a std::string return value. So my code changed from something like this:

```
void one_time_setup(const std::string & p1, int p2) {
   api_class api;
   api.setup (p1, special_number_to_string(p2));
}
```

to

```
void one_time_setup(const std::string & p1, int p2) {
   api_class api;
   const std::string p2_storage(special_number_to_string(p2));
   api.setup (string_view(&p1[0], p1.size()), string_view(&p2_storage[0], p2_storage.size()));
}
```

I **really** don't see what this change bought me as the API client, other than more code (to possibly screw up). The API call is less safe (due to the API no longer owning the storage for its parameters), probably saved my program 0 work (due to move optimizations compilers can do now), and even if it did save work, that would only be a couple of allocations that will not and would never be done after startup or in a big loop somewhere. Not for this API.

However, this approach seems to follow advice I see elsewhere, for example [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/356200/127619):

> As an aside, since C++17 you should avoid passing a const std::string&
>   in favor of a std::string_view:

I find that advice surprising, as it seems to be advocating universally replacing a relatively safe object with a less safe one (basically a glorified pointer and length), primarily for purposes of optimization.

So when *should* string_view be used, and when should it not?

Comment: you should never have to call the `std::string_view` constructor directly, you should just pass the strings to the method taking a `std::string_view` directly and it will automatically convert.

Comment: @Mgetz - Hmmm. I'm not (yet) using a full-blown C++17 compiler, so perhaps that's most of the issue. Still, the sample code [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view) seemed to indicate its required, at least when declaring one.

Comment: See my answer the conversion operator is in the `<string>` header and happens automatically. That code is deceiving and wrong.

Comment: "with a less safe one" how is a slice less safe than a string reference?

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Well, my thinking was that worst case with a string reference is generally the string changes out from under you (even if its const!). Worst case with a pointer is the underlying memory goes away, and your program either bombs, or gets taken over by the North Koreans. I prefer worst case A. :-)

Comment: That's still a problem if you have data races, don't use `std::string_view` when you need an owning `std::string`. But within the context of a single call a `std::string_view` is safe assuming no data races.

Comment: @T.E.D. The caller can just as easily free the string your reference is pointing to as they can free the memory the slice is pointing into.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. Does the functionality taking the value need to take ownership of the string? If so use `std::string` (non-const, non-ref). This option gives you the choice to explicitly move in a value as well if you know that it won't ever be used again in the calling context.
2. Does the functionality just read the string? If so use `std::string_view` (const, non-ref) this is because `string_view` can handle `std::string` and `char*` easily without issue and without making a copy. This should replace all `const std::string&` parameters.

Ultimately you should *never* need to call the `std::string_view` constructor like you are. `std::string` has a [conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_basic_string_view) that handles the conversion automatically.

Comment: Just to clarify one point, I'm thinking such a conversion operator would also take care of the worst of the lifetime issues, by making sure your RHS string value stays around for the entire length of the call?

Comment: @T.E.D. if you're just reading the value then the value will outlast the call. If you're taking ownership then it needs to outlast the call. Hence why I addressed both cases. The conversion operator just deals with making `std::string_view` easier to use. If a developer mis-uses it in an owning situation that's a programming error. `std::string_view` is strictly non-owning.

Comment: Why `const, non-ref` ? The parameter being const is up to the specific use, but in general is reasonable as non-const. And you missed **3. Can accept slices**

Comment: What's the problem of passing `const std::string_view &` in place of `const std::string &`?

Comment: @ceztko it's completely unnecessary and adds an extra indirection when accessing the data.

Comment: Ok, I asked if it was dangerous in some cases: since it's not, I think I will prefer to keep passing by const reference in most cases for better api clarity unless there are performance critical hot paths.

Comment: @ceztko you're obviously free to do that, I would generally suggest against it because it obfuscates the lifetime of the `string_view` by creating a temporary. Compilers can easily optimize most of this away, but clear lifetime is at least for me a must since this is a non-owning structure. I want the API to be clear I'm giving this as a borrow only.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I think it needs a third case to recommend what to do when the function doesn't require taking ownership or reading the string but simply passes it on to another function that may do 1 or 2.

Comment: So your recommendation is to make this interface decision based on an implementation detail of the function (that is, whether the function happens to store a copy of the input string value)?  Really?

Comment: @DonHatch That "implementation-detail" mirrors a major design-point, and is thus quite stable and non-surprising.

Comment: @Deduplicator It mirrors a major design point in some cases.  In many others, it does not; it varies from being a major design point, to a minor one, to an implementation detail (which may vary from implementation to implementation), in which case the question of how to make the interface decision remains unanswered.

Comment: @DonHatch - That seems to be a fundamental design problem with string_view. Its effectively a pointer to the string object its created from, created as a manual developer optimization. So the developer is *forced* to be cognizant of how its going to be used.

Answer (score 20):

A `std::string_view` brings some of the benefits of a `const char*` to C++: unlike `std::string`, a string_view

- does not own memory,
- does not allocate memory,
- can point into an existing string at some offset, and
- has one less level of pointer indirection than a `std::string&`.

This means a string_view can often avoid copies, without having to deal with raw pointers.

In modern code, `std::string_view` should replace nearly all uses of `const std::string&` function parameters. This should be a source-compatible change, since `std::string` declares a conversion operator to `std::string_view`.

Just because a string view doesn't help *in your specific use case* where you need to create a string anyway does not mean that it's a bad idea in general. The C++ standard library tends to be optimized for generality rather than for convenience. The “less safe” argument doesn't hold, as it shouldn't be necessary to create the string view yourself.

Comment: The big drawback of `std::string_view` is the absence of a  `c_str()` method, resulting in unnecessary, intermediate `std::string` objects that need to be constructed and allocated. This is especially a problem in low-level APIs.

Comment: @Matthias That's a good point, but I don't think its a huge drawback. A string view allows you to point into an existing string at some offset. That substring cannot be zero-terminated, you need a copy for that. A string view does not prohibit you from making a copy. It allows many string processing tasks that can be performed with iterators. But you are right that APIs that need a C string won't profit from views. A string reference can then be more appropriate.

Comment: @Matthias, doesn't string_view::data() match c_str()?

Comment: @Jeevaka a C string has to be zero-terminated, but a string view's data is usually not zero-terminated because it points into an existing string. E.g. if we have a string `abcdef\0` and a string view that points at the `cde` substring, there is no zero character after the `e` – the original string has an `f` there. The [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.view.access) also notes: “data() may return a pointer to a buffer that is not null-terminated. Therefore it is typically a mistake to pass data() to a function that takes just a const charT\* and expects a null-terminated string.”

Comment: @amon, I see, thanks. I didn't think about the sub-string scenario.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck The data already is a char pointer. The problem with C strings is not getting a char pointer, but that a C string must be null-terminated. See my previous comment for an example.

Comment: @amon - I just (finally) got the opportunity to use a full-blown C++17 compiler for writing an API using string_view, and I had to abandon string_view for exactly the reason Matthias mentioned. I actually *love* the idea of moving away from null-terminated strings *in theory*, but the fact that its API doesn't support them at all means string_view is worse than useless if the underlying code interfaces that string with null-terminated string routines or std::string. This includes not only old C char array handling routines and OS APIs, but C++ standard library operations like std::*fstream.

Answer (score 11):

> I find that advice surprising, as it seems to be advocating universally replacing a relatively safe object with a less safe one (basically a glorified pointer and length), primarily for purposes of optimization.

I think this is slightly misunderstanding the purpose of this. While it is an "optimization", you should really think of it as unshackling yourself from having to use a `std::string`.

Users of C++ have created *dozens* of different string classes. Fixed-length string classes, SSO-optimized classes with the buffer size being a template parameter, string classes that store a hash value used to compare them, etc. Some people even use COW-based strings. If there's one thing C++ programmers love to do, it's write string classes.

And that ignores strings which are created and owned by C libraries. Naked `char*`s, maybe with a size of some kind.

So if you're writing some library, and you take a `const std::string&`, the user now has to take whatever string they were using and copy it to a `std::string`. Maybe dozens of times.

If you want access to `std::string`'s string-specific interface, why should you have to *copy* the string? That's such a waste.

The principle reasons not to take a `string_view` as a parameter are:

1. If your ultimate goal is to pass the string to an interface that takes a NUL-terminated string (`fopen`, etc). `std::string` is guaranteed to be NUL terminated; `string_view` isn't. And it's very easy to substring a view to make it non-NUL-terminated; sub-stringing a `std::string` will copy the substring out into a NUL-terminated range.

   I wrote a special NUL-terminated string_view style type for exactly this scenario. You can do most operations, but not ones that break its NUL-terminated status (trimming from the end, for example).
2. Lifetime issues. If you really need to copy that `std::string` or otherwise have the array of characters outlive the function call, it's best to state this up-front by taking a `const std::string &`. Or just a `std::string` as a value parameter. That way, if they already have such a string, you can claim ownership of it immediately, and the caller can move into the string if they don't need to keep a copy of it around.

Comment: Is this true? The only *standard* string class I was aware of in C++ prior to this was std::string. There's some support for using char*'s as "strings" for backward compatibility with C, but I almost never need to use that. Sure, there are lots of user-defined third party classes for almost anything you can imagine, and strings are probably included in that, but I almost never have to use those.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Just because you "almost never have to use those" doesn't mean that *other people* don't routinely use them. `string_view` is a lingua franca type that can work with anything.

Comment: I can see that point. I was just unaware of C++ itself having "dozens of different string classes".

Comment: @T.E.D.: That's why I said "C++ as a programming environment", as opposed to "C++ as a language/library."

Comment: What does that even mean then? The superset of all code everyone has written anywhere? So I could equally say "C++ as a programming environment has thousands of container classes"?

Comment: @T.E.D.: "*So I could equally say "C++ as a programming environment has thousands of container classes"?*" And it does. But I can write algorithms that work with iterators, and any container classes that follow that paradigm will work with them. By contrast, "algorithms" that can take any contiguous array of characters were much harder to write. With `string_view`, it's easy.

Comment: Ironically, it occurs to me I've over the past few years taken to writing "range" classes for my containers that don't own the contained items. So now I don't know if I should argue against this, or that by limiting it to char arrays it doesn't go nearly far enough. Perhaps this whole string_view thing is [Alexandrescu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838721/c-iterators-considered-harmful) starting to win? I think I'll just quit while I'm behind... (oh, and +1 for you).

Comment: @T.E.D.: Character arrays are a very special case. They are exceedingly common, and different containers of contiguous characters differ only in how they manage their memory, not in how you iterate across the data. So having a single lingua franca range type that can cover all such cases without having to employ a template makes sense. Generalization beyond this is the province of the Range TS and templates.

Comment: Another reason to take a `const std::string &` is when that string will just be used as the key to an associative container, like a `std::map<std::string, Foo>`.  If you take a `std::string_view` instead, you'll have to make a temporary copy before you can use it as a key.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Not since C++14, which allows [heterogeneous lookup for `map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) (though you do have to ask for it explicitly). `operator[]` and `at` can't do it, because they have to be able to construct a key if it is not in the container.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  Cool, but that seems limited to `find`, which I haven't needed very often.  `operator[]`, `at`, and `erase` (by key) are all fundamental ways of working with associative containers.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: They are fundamental ways for *inserting items* into associative containers. Well, not `erase` obviously, but you get my point: they don't merely search for a key in the object. Insertion requires that a key exists. And `erase` can be called with the result of `find`.